# %7Bid%7D showing this except ID,, Route::get('Images/{id}/show','ImageController@index');

Tags: php, html, laravel, cakephp-2.0

`%7Bid%7D` Showing this except real id 
`http://localhost/laravel/public/Images/%7Bid%7D/show`

but when i change this `%7Bid%7D` in to number it also work but now shows automatically.

> Routes: Route::get('Images/{id}/show','ImageController@index');

Comment: try `urlencode($id)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong when calling route.

ex: if you want to make route to show image with id 2 in your view you must do something like:

```
<a href="{{ route('images.show', $image->id)}}">link</a>
or 
<a href="{{ url('Images/'.$image->id.'/show') }}">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//simple change (->get();  into  ->first();


public function userprofile($id)
    {

        $userdata = User::where('id', $id)->first();
        // $userdata = Auth::login($user)->where('role', '=', 'admin');

        return view('layouts.userdetail')->With('userdata', $userdata);

    }
```